# fwrite doesn't write properly

Tags: c, windows, fwrite

I've been trying to write a simple string to a file in C with `fwrite()`.

When I define a simple string as:

```
char str[]="Hello World!";
```

and write it to a file as:

```
fwrite(str, sizeof(char), sizeof(str), fp);
```

Everything seems to work fine.

But as I make a custom string with `sprintf_s`, the output file I get is:

> ﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾畒湮湩⁧湁祬敺浉条⹥硥⁥湯椠杭〰⸱灪㩧爠

Though `printf` func will print the string correctly

The Complete Code:

```
#define MAX_ELEMENT_LENGTH 512


void GenerateResultLine(char *resultLineBuffer, int maxLength,
                            const char *result) {
    const char * TEMPLATE= "Running Result: %s";
    sprintf_s(resultLineBuffer, maxLength, TEMPLATE, result);
}


void PrintResultToFile(char* exitCode,  FILE* resultFile) {
    char    resultLine[ MAX_ELEMENT_LENGTH ];

    GenerateResultLine(resultLine, MAX_ELEMENT_LENGTH, exitCode);
    printf("LINE: %s\n",resultLine);


    fwrite(resultLine, sizeof(char), sizeof(resultLine), resultFile);

}
```

Does anyone have any idea why??
Thanks

Comment: What kind of string?  And how are you putting the values into `str`?

Comment: `char *str[]` is an array of pointers. Probably not what you intended?

Comment: this is my `sprintf` func:

Comment: `const char * TEMPLATE = "Running %s";
 char result[]="OK";
 sprintf_s(resultLine, maxLength, TEMPLATE, 
    imageTitle, result);`

Comment: How did you allocate `resultLine`? How did you define `maxLength`?

Comment: `char resultLine[256];` and `int maxLength=256;`

Comment: ***Show Complete Code*** (not just two disconnected lines... are they even in the same function?)

Comment: I'm curious that you didn't get a compiler error with your code..

Comment: Why shoult I get a compiler ERROR? when I define resultLine to `char resultLine[]="Hello World";` and put the call to `GenerateResultLine` in a comment, everything seems to work fine

Comment: Did you paste the exact code you have or written here something from scratch? Hint: look at `resultLineBuffer`

Comment: For starters `fwrite(resultLine, sizeof(char), sizeof(resultLine), resultFile)` shoudl be `fwrite(resultLine, sizeof(char), strlen(resultLine) + 1, resultFile)`.

Comment: Dear Mihai Maruseac, do you really want me to paste a 200 lines of code?? Anyway you should know I truly appreciate your tremendous help

Comment: Need to see how file is opened.

Comment: `resultFile  = fopen( "File.txt", "w" );`

Comment: No, but I want you to paste the exact lines in there, not rewrite them :). Your function has `resultLineBuffer` as arugment yet you use `resultLine` inside. If it compiles then it means you have a `resultLine` globally defined and you're modifying that instead of the one in `PrintResultToFile`. If it doesn't compile...

Comment: In `GenerateResultLine()` the first parameter is `resultLineBuffer` and `sprintf_s()` first paramter is a different variable called `resultLine`.  Where did `resultLine` come from?  How is `resultLineBuffer`  used?

Comment: "Though printf func will print the string correctly" and what is that string?

Comment: First, Thx for your help, sec, I've modified the function so I wouldn't paste a large code in my post.. sorry for this mistake.. I've  edited the post once more

Comment: The string is `resultLine`, I've updated the post as i mentioned in my last comment

Comment: @Isaac, what is the _value_ of that correctly printed string?  Something line "LINE: abcd\n"

Comment: @Isaac: Now, make sure what you have posted here is **exactly** what you have in your code because otherwise all of us will be hunting for dead horses.

Comment: for example, in the screen i get `LINE: Running Result: OK`, and in the "File.txt" i get things like `⁧湁祬敺﻾﻾﻾﻾`

Comment: @Mihai Maruseac, now these lines were compiled and tested...

Comment: @Isaac Why are you writing 512 chars in `fwrite()` instead of `strlen(resultLine) + 1?  That a whole lot of undefined stuff after the "LINE: Running Result: OK".  When you say "i get things like ⁧湁祬敺﻾﻾﻾﻾", did the file first contain "LINE: Running Result: OK"?  If so, there's your answer.

Comment: YOU GOT IT!!!!!!! I added `resultLine[ 0 ] = '\0';` after the line `char resultLine[ MAX_ELEMENT_LENGTH ];` and it WORKED!!! Now it refers to it as a string, THANKS A LOT!! please publish it as an answer so everyone could learn

Comment: I really don't think that `resultLine[ 0 ] = '\0';` is the exact solution :)

Comment: But it worked.. Do you have any other solution?

Comment: @Isaac Did you change to `strlen(resultLine)`?

Comment: no, I didn't, just `sizeof(resultLine)`

Comment: I do not see, like @Mihai Maruseac, how `resultLine[ 0 ] = '\0'` solved your problem.  But I still maintain you need to change your write length to reflect the defined part of `resultLine`.

Comment: I'll explain: befor I added the `resultLine[ 0 ] = '\0'`, when I used fwrite, it took all 512 bytes from somewhere allocated memory, which is rubbish. when I added the `'\0'` I actually told him to "stop here" and refer this memory space as a string

Comment: Where `here` is the beginning of the string.

Comment: Exactly, thats a greate intuition you guys have

Comment: You're not getting it, your code is still wrong/you are looking somewhere else.

Comment: What would you suggest?

Comment: All of the solutions were given here. Now you only need to look properly at your code and your output to see what's happening.

Comment: Please move extended discussion to [chat], thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code is writing uninitialized data to the file

```
// Code writes entire buffer to the file,
// even though only the leading bytes are defined via a previous sprintf_s()
fwrite(resultLine, sizeof(char), sizeof(resultLine), resultFile);

// Instead
size_t n = strlen(resultLine);
n++; // If the final `\0` is desired.
if (n != fwrite(resultLine, sizeof(char), n, resultFile)) {
  handle_error();
}
```

Comment: I upvoted because that's the reason why his code was broken, even though he fails to acknowledge that and persists in making claims that his own changes are good.